# How to design my framework of EventTrigger in game with no existing engine?

Tags: c++, architecture

I'm now learning game designing and to start, SuperMarioBro is the game I'm now going to finish with little engine. I want to design a trigger so that when Mario hit the question mark, the mushroom or the gold coins or white flower etc will appear. So when hitting it, trigger is triggered and it will call its callback function to spawn different things to make it more decoupling.

So my question is that how can I design a perfect framework of Event Trigger like this, I just know it in general.

- Should I set trigger in the object that I want to trigger?
- And should I make a trigger manager?
- And how can these triggers do?

Comment: Hi seventeezz, I think your question is a little too broad and vague. I suggest you first come up with an idea of design then ask specific questions about it.

Comment: You may also want to ask your question to the stackexchange game dev community on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question is general, I will give you a naive idea of how *I* would personally start thinking about it.

I suppose your game already have an event manager, to which you can register to receive notifications of particular events occurring (might be using the [observer design pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/observer.html)).

I would then have a TriggerManager registered as a receiver for any event you might want to trigger specific actions for. For each type of observed event, the TriggerManager would contain two things :

- a filter
- a handler

The filter would be used to decide if the event fits the wanted condition (e.g. an entity moved within range area).

If the event passes the filter, the handler is executed in reaction to that event : an action/command/event sent to another entity or system.

Also, at some point in the past I read [that post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/3ygzm5/best_way_to_implement_trigger_events_for_rpg_games/) on reddit (see comments), which I found quite inspiring too, and describes a different approach.

You may also want to ask your question to the stackexchange game dev community on [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Hope this gives you some ideas.